# Nested c program

Tags: c

Please help. My program is not working.

It should take N from the input of the user and calculate the function of nested e.
For example

N=4
e=2+1/2(1+1/3(1+1/4))

```
#include <stdio.h>  
#include <stdlib.h>  

double nested_e(int N)  
{
    double e, factor_e, a;  
    int n;  

    if(N==1)  
        e=2;  
    else if(N==2)  
        e=2+0.5;  
    else  
    {  
         a=1;  
         for(n=2;n<N;n++)  
         {  
             factor_e = a * 1/N +1;  
             a = factor_e;  
             N--;  
         }  
         e = factor_e + 2 ;  
    }  
    printf("%lf", e);  
    return 0;
}  

int main(void)  
{
    int s;  
    printf("Enter the number : \n");  
    scanf("%d", &s);  
    double nested_e(s);  
    return 0;  
}
```

Comment: What does "My program is not working" mean? In what way doesn't it work? Also, you should probably add the 'homework' tag.

Comment: It'd help if you told us what is going wrong. Hehe. `factor_e`

Comment: it does not have errors but the problem is that it is not displaying anything

Comment: Wait, why is your function returning a double when the only possible return value is `0`?

Comment: @Cfinal: increase the warning level of your compiler.

Comment: I've tagged it as homework, please remove if it's inappropriate.

Comment: Please use spaces in a consistent way. If you write `);` and then somewhere else `) ;` this is bad style. Are you using *gcc*? Have you tried compiling with `-Wall -Wextra` options? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: I am guessing this is where the error is… `double nested_e(s);`

Comment: "it does not have errors but the problem is that it is not displaying anything" So why didn't you say that in the first place? And how do you know it does not have errors? It certainly has *bugs*.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you turn your logic inside out. Instead of starting at the `2 +`, (increasing `n`) start at the `(1 + 1/4)` and work your way out (decreasing `n`).

Comment: The code *does* start at 1 + 1/4; that's the first value assigned to `factor_e`. But the loop increments `n` as well as decrementing `N`. The loop should be `for( n = N; n > 0; --n ){ ...}` and then add 1 to the result, with no need for the special cases.

Answer (score 1):

This line is very wrong:

> double nested_e(s);

If you want to call existing function, you need no to specify its return type.

So, change this line to

> nested_e(s);

Answer (score 0):

I see many things wrong, but this is homework so... you should not have special cases for N==1 and N==2, they are both not special in any way so your algorithm could be more general. Think a little bit harder and you'll get it!

There are tools to help you in this kind of situation. Start by placing `printfs` everywhere so you understand what is going on. If you know how to do it, you could also use a `debugger`. Then you can also try to add an option for more warnings to the compiler.

Comment: Don't you mean `N==1` and `N==2`? :)

Comment: Yes, I was using math notation not C, sorry.